# EF6.x Moving from Database First to Code First with Table per Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have always been very much more at ease starting new projects with the Database first ostensibly because I'm more comfortable working in SSMS.  Nonetheless it does one good to learn new tricks so I have decided to reverse the process, beginning with something relatively simple in order to learn the correct technique and potential pitfalls.  To that end consider the following scenario for a very simple business that buys and sells goods.  It will have both Customers and Suppliers and as it grows, Employees.  To begin with I have kept it simple dealing with just Customers and Suppliers but factoring in the provision for the possibility that a Customer could also become a supplier and vice-versa.

Thinking about this from a purely programing perspective it's clear that Customers and Suppliers have common properties and given that it's also clear that it would make sense for them to inherit those from a base class.  From an Entity Framework perspective this suggests to me a Table per Type Inheritance.

So in a simple Class Library I have defined the following Entities:

```
     public abstract class EntityBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateModified { get; set; }

        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
    }

  [Table("Contacts", Schema = "Contacts")]
    public abstract class Contact : EntityBase
    {


        public string ContactName { get; set; }

        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string CompanyName { get; set; }


        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string WorkTelephoneNumber { get; set; }


        public string MobileTelephone1 { get; set; }

        public string MobileTelephone2 { get; set; }
    }

 [Table("Customers", Schema = "Contacts")]
    public class Customer : Contact
    {
        public DateTime? FirstInvoiceDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }
    }

  [Table("Suppliers", Schema = "Contacts")]
    public class Supplier : Contact
    {
        public DateTime DateStarted { get; set; }

        public DateTime? FirstInvoiceDate { get; set; }

    }
```

There is a simple Customer Context as shown;

```
 public class CustomerContext : DbContext
{

    public CustomerContext() : base("Ef6Test")
    {
    }



    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }




    private void AddTimestamps()
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is EntityBase && (x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified));

        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            if (entity.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                ((EntityBase)entity.Entity).DateCreated = DateTime.UtcNow;

            }

            ((EntityBase)entity.Entity).DateModified = DateTime.UtcNow;

        }
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        AddTimestamps();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

}
```

Suppliers has a replica of this.

If I then run migrations against this it will create a database containing a Contacts table that has a  one to zero or one relationship with Customers and Suppliers (pretty much exactly what I want).

I then set out to test this creating a simple console application with the following code;

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        InsertCustomers();
        InsertSuppliers();
        ShowCustomers();
        ShowSuppliers();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void InsertCustomers()
    {
        var customer1 = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = "Mickey",
            LastName = "Mouse",
            DateStarted = DateTime.Now
        };

        var customer2 = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = "Fred",
            LastName = "Flintstone",
            DateStarted = DateTime.Now
        };

        using (var context = new CustomerContext())
        {
            context.Customers.Add(customer1);
            context.Customers.Add(customer2);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }


    private static void InsertSuppliers()
    {
        var supplier1 = new Supplier
        {
            FirstName = "Roger",
            LastName = "Rabbit",
            DateStarted = DateTime.Now
        };

        var supplier2 = new Supplier
        {
            FirstName = "Wylie",
            LastName = "Kyote",
            DateStarted = DateTime.Now
        };

        using (var context = new SupplierContext())
        {
            context.Suppliers.Add(supplier1);
            context.Suppliers.Add(supplier2);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    static void ShowCustomers()
    {
        using (var ctxt = new CustomerContext())
        {
            var customers = ctxt.Customers.ToList();
            foreach (var cust in ctxt.Customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{cust.FirstName} {cust.LastName}");
            }
        }
    }
    static void ShowSuppliers()
    {
        using (var ctxt = new SupplierContext())
        {
            var suppliers = ctxt.Suppliers.ToList();
            foreach (var sup in ctxt.Suppliers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{sup.FirstName} {sup.LastName}");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void MakeCustomerASupplier()
    {
        var modCust = new Supplier
        {
            // would like Fred Flintstone to become a supplier as well.
        };
    }
}
```

When I Run this I get an exception on the first call to Base Save Changes in the customer context;

[image]

All of the columns refered to in the exception are either nullable or handled prior to calling base SaveChanges (as is the case with DateCreated and DateModified, or set on the sqlserver as is the case with RowVersion.

Clearly I have either misunderstood the correct syntax to do this or misunderstood the whole notion of Table Per Type inheritance.  Is this a reasonable approach to this sort of situation ( I envisage at a later date for example that you might want to restrict access to employee information so amalgamating everything into a giant Contacts table seems wrong)?

If the approach is reasonable but the syntax wrong could someone enlighten me as to the correct approach, and also from there how one might at a later date get Fred Flintstone to become a supplier as well as the customer that he currently is (or would be if the data had been saved back to the database!)?

Comment: The design looks ok, only the separate contexts look suspicious. Are you sure you are accessing the same database created by the migration? From exception looks like the columns are missing in the db table. Can you even read from it, e.g. call `ShowCustomers` first. and turn logging on -  `ctxt.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;`

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for your comment.  I honestly didn't know whether there should or shouldn't be separate contexts (still learning!!).  If I go into SSMS and add some contacts  (with just first and last name) and then add references to two of those in the Customers table when I run ShowCustomers() , with or without logging, I get results back, but not interesting if I just try show contacts , nor can I add Contacts on their own (after I removed abstract from the class definition).  I know from logs that I hit the database so it must be a syntactical error.

Comment: The logging was just to see the EF executed SQL commands. As for the `DbContext` derived class, think of it as *database*, with `DbSet`s being *tables*. Hence I would create single `DbContext` derived class, put `Customers` and `Suppliers` `DbSet`s in it, keep the `Contact` class abstract and try again.

Comment: @IvanStoev  Well it appears that the real issue came down to the fact that when the database was created it did a direct mapping of DateTime to DateTime on SqlServer (I'm using sql2016). Once I had overridden OnModelCreating and got it to ensure that all DateTime types were mapped to datetime2 sql types I'm able to create new customers and suppliers directly as I had expected to be able to do with the contacts class defined as abstract.  Now I just need to figure out how to make a customer a supplier as well.

Comment: Ok, cool. Just to let you know, EF does not allow changing the inherited entity type once it has been created. In other words, if the created `Contact` type is `Customer`, you can't change it to `Supplier` except you do something directly in database with raw SQL. Cheers.

Comment: @IvanStoev  I don't want to change the inheirited entity type.  Suppose that you were my customer, and I initially set you up as a new customer.  Then you start making something that I want to buy.  You're still a customer, but now I want to add you as a supplier as well.  That's the functionality I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the error illustrated in the question was being caused by the fact that when the database was being created from the migrations the dot Net type DateTime was being directly mapped to the SqlType datetime.

By adding the following code to the relevant Context(s)

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

I was able to successfully add Customers and Suppliers as I had thought that it should be possible to do. At the time of writing this I have yet to solve the second part of my question but hopefully this will make life a little easier for anyone coming across this question through a search.